# Creating client certificate with certificate uploaded in Azure key vault

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I have created a pfx file using openssl commands as below

```
opensl genrsa -out private_key.pem 4096
openssl req -new -x509  -key private_key.pem -out public_key.cer  -days 100 -sha512 -sub "/CN=self-signed"
openssl pkcs12 -export -out samplepkcs12.pfx -inkey private_key.pem -in public_key.cer
```

Then I have imported my pfx file to my Azure Key vault.

Now in my azure function, I need to download this certificate and create a client certificate.
I am tried below code

```
DefaultAzureCredential defaultCredential = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder()
           .managedIdentityClientId("<MANAGED_IDENTITY_CLIENT_ID>")
           .build();
        
// Azure SDK client builders accept the credential as a parameter
 SecretClient client = new SecretClientBuilder()
         .vaultUrl("https://{YOUR_VAULT_NAME}.vault.azure.net")
         .credential(defaultCredential)
          .buildClient();
KeyVaultSecret certificateSecret = client.getSecret(<certificateName>);
IClientCertificate clientCertificate = 
          ClientCredentialFactory.createFromCertificate(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(certificateSecret.getBytes()),"<password>");
```

But I am getting below exception

```
java.IO.Exception to DerInputStream rejects type 77
at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.toDerInputStream(DerValue.java:873)
at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCSKeyStore.java:1994)
```

Any suggestion on the right way of uploading(if my approach is wrong) or retreiving certificate and creating a clientCertificate ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Secret library. Instead you should use the Certificate library described here:
https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-security-keyvault-certificates/4.3.2/index.html

```
CertificateClient certificateClient = new CertificateClientBuilder()
    .vaultUrl("<your-key-vault-url>")
    .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
    .buildClient();

KeyVaultCertificate certificate = certificateClient.getCertificate("<certificate-name>");
```